# MySql and PHP loop to draw squares with x,y coordinates

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, mysqli

I updated my code. It has Javascript,PHP,JSON and JQuery. I’m reading X,Y Coordinates from 
MySQL Database. 
I am now using 3 files : coordinate_array, db_conn and map.php

**Connection :**

```
<?php 
  //declaring connection 
  $db_user = "u"; 
  $db_pwd = "p"; 
  $db_server = "v"; 
  $db_name = "sandbox"; 
  //1. connection to the database 
  $conn = mysqli_connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_pwd); 
//check connection 
  if(!$conn){ 
   die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error()); 
  }else{ 
   echo "connected to MySQL<br>"; 
  } 
// 2. Select a database to use 
  $db_select = mysqli_select_db($conn, $db_name); 
  if (!$db_select) { 
  die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error()); 
  } 
 mysqli_close($conn); 
 ?>
```

In **coordinate_array:** I am making a multidimensional arrays so I can draw all of the rectangles being 
fetch by my query, I then use json_encode($desk). I am ignoring the coordinate_id from the table 
since I only need x,y values for the Javascript part.

```
<?php 
 $select_coordinate_query = "SELECT * FROM coordinates";// WHERE coordinate_id ='1' 
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$select_coordinate_query); 
 //see if query is good 
 if($result === false) { 
  die(mysqli_error()); 
 } 
 //array that will have number of desks in map area
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){  
  //get desk array count 
  $desk = array( array("x" => $row['x_coord']), 
     array("y" => 
 $row['y_coord']) 
    ); 
  // Frame JSON 
 // Return the x, y JSON here 
 echo json_encode($desk); 
  } //end while loop 
 ?>
```

In **map.php** : I am trying to get those value with the use of JQuery. I want to get the values and run a
loop that will execute my Paint function which will keep drawing rectangles for every row thats in the
table. I am very new with JSON and JQuery and starting to use it.

```
<div class="section_a" > 
 <p>Section A</p> 
 <canvas id="imageView" width="600" 
 height="500"></canvas> 
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
 /* call the php that has the php array which is json_encoded */ 
 $.getJSON('coordinate_array.php', function(data) { 
/* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */ 
 if(data != null){ 
  $.parseJSON(data); 
  $(data).each(Paint(x,y)){ 
 //get values from json 
 //for every row run the functionpaint by passing X,Y coordinate  
 });//end getJson 
}//end if 
}); //end rdy func 
});//end func 
   //function to paint rectangles 
   function Paint(x,y) 
{ 
var ctx, cv; 
  cv = document.getElementById('imageView'); 
  ctx = cv.getContext('2d'); 
  ctx.lineWidth = 5; 
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000'; 
  //x-axis,y-axis,x-width,y-width 
  ctx.strokeRect(x, y, x+100 , y+100); 
} 
   </script> 
 </div> <!-- end div section_a -->
```

Also, do I have the correct syntax for my  when including my jquery file.. its in the same as 
every other file that I’m using.

Another question I have is: Is it good to include the connection file in every file and close it at the end 
or keep the connection open in my file where I havethe connection established?

Thank you in advance it’s much appreciated!

Comment: Not an answer but the code you presented is unmaintainable mess. Consider at least not mixing HTML, JS, PHP and SQL in one file.

Comment: You're creating a new canvas for every set of coordinates you pull from your database. I'm sure that's not what you want to do. Also, don't use `mysql_*()` - it's deprecated. Use `mysqli_*()` for new code.

Comment: Note that MySQL has [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/spatial-datatypes.html](native support) for co-ordinate systems data. You shouldn't be using `mysql_*()` _or_ `mysqli_*()`; rather use PDO or some other abstraction layer.

And yes, separate your code if you want some useful suggestions for how to improve it.

Comment: thanks guys for the replies I'm going to look into PDO for sure to improve this code but before doing that I posted my updated code. Also, I know some of you are saying that I shouldn't include JS with PHP, so how else can I put my values for the canvas if that's the only way that I can think of? If you guys can please explain how to seperate the JS from PHP it would be helpful. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest a better way to keep the code simple and clean.

1. Create a web service interface to return the x,y data in an array.
2. This interface can read from the database and shall return x,y co-ordinates in JSON.
3. Use Jquery Ajax call to get these details and paint the screen.
4. Better use RxJS for easier painting.

Here is the sample code for web interface:

```
    <?php
// I assume you have not created connection object -- I don't see one in your code
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db"); // replace the credentials and db name
// Check connection
$select_coordinate_query = "SELECT * FROM coordinates";
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$select_coordinate_query);  
//see if query is good -- ## Better check for row count
if($result === false) 
{
    die(mysqli_error()); 
}
//array that will have number of desks in map area
while($row == mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){   // double equal to missing...you will never receive the data
    //get desk array count
    //THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP**
    $desk = array( array("x" => $row['x_coord']),array("y" => $row['y_coord']) ); 
    //x, y coordinates 
    $x_pos = $desk['x'];
    $y_pos = $desk['y'];
    //x,y width and height
    $x_size = $x_pos + 40;
    $y_size = $y_pos + 10;    
    // Frame JSON
    // Return the x, y JSON here
} //end while loop  ?>
```

Here is the client code:

```
<div class="section_a" >
    <p>Section A</p>

    <canvas id="imageView" width="600" height="500"></canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callWS()
        {
            // Make XHR call here and read JSON values 
            // Loop through and paint by calling f(Paint)
        }

        function Paint(x,y)
        {
            var ctx, cv;
            cv = document.getElementById('imageView');
            ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
            ctx.lineWidth = 5;
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
            ctx.strokeRect(x, y,100 , 100); 

        }
    </script>
</div>
```

You can call these functions in any event you would want. Code is untested. Note that you were creating Canvas many times earlier but here it's created once and you can draw squares on the canvas.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help I updated my code and having trouble doing JSON and Jquery. mind if you look at it? thanks its appreciated!